# highrise API, put unprocessable entity , 37 Signals

Tags: api, put, guzzle, highrise, 37-signals

i´m  playing arround with the  [HIGHRISE API](https://github.com/basecamp/highrise-api/blob/master/sections/people.md), and they understood the meaning of rest, its pretty cool and at some points gracefully forgivingly, but

has anybody any idea why the xml i `PUT` is not accepted ?

here is some relevant logging :

```
2014-02-23 00:00:04] app.INFO: Updating:Person:Highrise-API =  people/11834527375.xml [] []
[2014-02-23 00:00:04] app.INFO: request body is :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person>
  <first-name><![CDATA[Johnny]]></first-name>
  <last-name><![CDATA[B. Good]]></last-name>
  <visible-to><![CDATA[Everyone]]></visible-to>
  <subject_datas type="array">
    <subject_data>
      <subject_field_id type="integer"><![CDATA[43212]]></subject_field_id>
      <value><![CDATA[dsa328394OOKD323H]]></value>
    </subject_data>
    <subject_data>
      <subject_field_id type="integer"><![CDATA[470259]]></subject_field_id>
      <value><![CDATA[provider://w184071823/fmdks/2032]]></value>
    </subject_data>
    <subject_data>
      <subject_field_id type="integer"><![CDATA[469130]]></subject_field_id>
      <value><![CDATA[CORE]]></value>
    </subject_data>
    <subject_data>
      <subject_field_id type="integer"><![CDATA[469132]]></subject_field_id>
      <value><![CDATA[Way too cool]]></value>
    </subject_data>
  </subject_datas>
  <contact-data>
    <phone-numbers>
      <phone-number type="array">
        <number><![CDATA[081 6418273]]></number>
        <location><![CDATA[Work]]></location>
      </phone-number>
    </phone-numbers>
    <addresses type="array">
      <address>
        <city><![CDATA[New York City]]></city>
        <country><![CDATA[US]]></country>
        <state><![CDATA[New York]]></state>
        <street><![CDATA[Siplingerstreet 11]]></street>
        <zip><![CDATA[87527]]></zip>
        <location><![CDATA[Work]]></location>
      </address>
    </addresses>
  </contact-data>
</person>
 [] []
[2014-02-23 00:00:04] app.INFO: request set [] []
[2014-02-23 00:00:04] app.ERROR: Guzzle/3.8.1 curl/7.28.1 PHP/5.4.10 - [2014-02-22T23:00:04+00:00] "PUT /people/11834527375.xml HTTP/1.1" 422 103 [] []
[2014-02-23 00:00:04] app.INFO: Caught client-error-exception in HighriseService updatePerson(): exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException' with message 'Client error response
[status code] 422
[reason phrase] Unprocessable Entity
```

i dont see the error :/ 
I´m very sure the subject_field_id´s are correct and those custom fields are set
Posting e.g saving that xml works, i saw from the response that are fields were set,

only thing i can guess is, that i´m trying to PUT a version where nothing has changed, 
is that the problem ?

because my code only checks if that person exists at all and if so update it instead of creating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get back some XML in the body of the response. It should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<errors>
  <error>Phone number '555-555-5555' has already been taken</error>
</errors>
```

If you include the id for the existing phone number in your PUT request, then we know that you want to update the existing address, rather than adding a new one: https://github.com/basecamp/highrise-api/blob/master/sections/people.md#update-person

> Contact data and Subject data that include an id will be updated, data that doesn’t will be assumed to be new and created from scratch. To remove a piece of data, prefix its id with a minus sign (e.g. -1).

Comment: This is it ! thank you very very much ! 
I never looked at the response body of the thrown exception, next time i will ! thanks